# How do I generate a class diagram from Edmx Diagram in ADO.NET Entity FrameWork 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, poco, class-diagram, edmx

How do I generate a class diagram from Edmx Diagram in ADO.NET Entity FrameWork 4?

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You must add manually a new class diagram and put all entity classes generated by EF to that new diagram. Alternatively if you understand content of EDMX you can write custom T4 or XSLT template to convert it to other format representing for example UML class diagram.